# Scan down a column until you hit text, and then paste the number of the first and last row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically, I exported a list of names into Excel. I'm trying to write a formula to let me sort through the names and extract some information, however I can't quite get it to work.

(now referring to the image attached, which is an image of what the finished result should look like)

Assuming we're starting at A2, I need to scan down ColumnA until I hit text.

So for this first scan, It should start at A2, and end at A5

After it finishes the scan, it needs to go to column B and paste the row# immediately after A2, then it needs to go to column C and paste the row# immediately before A5. In some cases they will be the same number, and that's ok.

If the distance between the two rows is 0, like A8 and A9, then I don't want it to show anything.

I need to use this formula for a list of ~30 names. Could anyone help me make something like this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkQL1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formulas:

For Start column (column B):

```
=+IF(AND(A2="",A1<>""),ROW(A2),"")
```

For End column (column C):

```
=+IF(AND(A2="",A3<>""),ROW(A2),"")
```